# How To change PE Import Address Table Using C#?

Tags: c#, portable-executable

I need to make a small application to modify an exe file (any exe) by replacing an imported function address (in Import Address Table section) with another function address (i have created) so the Question is : **how to use C# to parse an exe (pe) and find the address of Import Address Table to alter an imported function address ?**

i found this method on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/kb/system/hooksys.aspx)

note : i dont know how to work with pe in c#

thanks for help .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i dont know how to work with pe in c#

This is the issue you'll want to address :)

A PE is just a file. Microsoft has a pretty good document that describes its format on their web site. You may have to register in order to be able to download it. It's called the Microsoft Portable Executable and Common Object File Format Specification.

http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/platform/firmware/pecoff.mspx

If you're going to replace a function, presumably that function is in memory, so you're modifying the image in memory, not the actual PE. Luckily the format of the PE in memory is conceptually the same as it is on disk - now, you just deal with memory offsets rather than file offsets.

Redirecting an import address table (IAT) function is conceptually easy. This should get you going:

1) Locate the pointer to the PE header within the file header, which is the very beginning of the image.

2) Locate the pointer to the IAT within the PE header.

3) Iterate over the entries in the IAT until you find the name of the function you wish to redirect.

4) Unprotect the function pointer location for your desired IAT entry with VirtualProtect since it usually sits in a write-protected section.

5) Write in your own proc pointer on top of what was previously there.

6) Restore the previous protection (might not actually be necessary)

7) Done.

Comment: thanks , but how to use c# to do these steps , should i open the exe as regular file ? how to find iat address ?

Comment: Assuming you're modifying an already running process, use ReadProcessMemory, WriteProcessMemory. If you're trying to modify a PE on disk, then that's quite a bit more complicated because you now have to somehow embed your modified routine in the PE.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [PeNet](https://github.com/secana/PeNet) library to add a new import with just one line of code. For an example see here: [Adding Imports](http://secana.github.io/PeNet/articles/imports.html)

```cs
// Open executable on disk
var peFile = new PeFile("myapp.exe"); 
// add function StartPage of the gdi32.dll to the import table of the opened .exe file inside memory. It doesn't write changes to disk.
peFile.AddImport("gdi32.dll", "StartPage");
// save changes to disk
File.WriteAllBytes("D:\\PathWhereToSaveFile\\nameOfTheFile.exe", peFile.RawFile.ToArray());
```

Original answer by the creator of the library is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62216546/6693304