# Add an entry to the import table of PE

Tags: windows, dll, automation, portable-executable

I'm looking for a command line program to add an entry to the import table of a PE file.
My goal is to add a new imported function from an external DLL to my EXE, and then with ollydbg insert new code using code caves. The new code will use the newly imported function.

Acctualy I've achived my goal, but to add a new entry to the import table I used [Stud_PE](http://www.cgsoftlabs.ro/studpe.html), which is a GUI application and I want to automate this part of the process.

I'd consider programmatically solutions, but I'm affraid the PE structure is too complex for me to learn and explore in the time frame I have. Moreover if an implementation is already exists, it would be a shame not to use it. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found what is was looking for.

**m-PEFile** for c++: http://forum.exetools.com/showpost.php?s=17e7516356489bb9dd17e294e147ef96&p=60183&postcount=3

Also check out **pefile** for python: http://code.google.com/p/pefile/

And **PE/COFF 4J** for java: http://pecoff4j.sourceforge.net/

PE/COFF 4J has limited functionality in my opinion, but maybe you'll find it helpful.

Code: `PEFile.h`

```
/*******************************************************************************
********************************   Team AT4RE   ********************************
********************************************************************************
*******************  PLEASE DON'T CHANGE/REMOVE THIS HEADER  *******************
********************************************************************************
**                                                                            **
**  Title:      PEFile class.                                                 **
**  Desc:       A handy class to manipulate pe files.                         **
**  Author:     MohammadHi [ in4matics at hotmail dot com ]                   **
**  WwW:        AT4RE      [ http://www.at4re.com ]                           **
**  Date:       2008-01-28                                                    **
**                                                                            **
********************************************************************************
*******************************************************************************/

/*
[  PE File Format   ]
---------------------
|    DOS Header     |
---------------------
|     DOS Stub      |
---------------------
|     PE Header     |
---------------------
|   Section Table   |
---------------------
|      Padding      |
---------------------
|     Section 1     |
---------------------
|     Section 2     |
---------------------
|        ...        |
---------------------
|     Section n     |
---------------------*/

//==============================================================================
#pragma once
#pragma pack(1)
//==============================================================================
#include <windows.h>
//==============================================================================
#define MAX_SECTION_COUNT       64
#define SECTION_IMPORT          "@.import"
#define SECTION_RESERV          "@.reserv"
//==============================================================================
struct PE_DOS_HEADER {
    WORD   Signature;
    WORD   LastPageBytes;
    WORD   NumberOfPages;
    WORD   Relocations;
    WORD   HeaderSize;
    WORD   MinMemory;
    WORD   MaxMemory;
    WORD   InitialSS;
    WORD   InitialSP;
    WORD   Checksum;
    WORD   InitialIP;
    WORD   InitialCS;
    WORD   RelocTableOffset;
    WORD   Overlay;
    WORD   Reserved1[4];
    WORD   OemId;
    WORD   OemInfo;
    WORD   Reserved2[10];
    LONG   PEHeaderOffset;
};
struct PE_DOS_STUB {
    char*   RawData;
    DWORD   Size;
};
struct PE_SECTION_DATA {
    DWORD   Offset;
    char*   RawData;
    DWORD   Size;
};
struct PE_IMPORT_FUNCTION {
    char*               FunctionName;
    int                 FunctionId;
    PE_IMPORT_FUNCTION* Next;
};
struct PE_IMPORT_DLL {
    char*               DllName;
    PE_IMPORT_FUNCTION* Functions;
    PE_IMPORT_DLL*  Next;
};
//==============================================================================
typedef IMAGE_NT_HEADERS PE_NT_HEADERS;
typedef IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER PE_SECTION_HEADER;
//==============================================================================
class PEFile {
public:
    PE_DOS_HEADER       dosHeader;
    PE_DOS_STUB         dosStub;
    PE_NT_HEADERS       peHeaders;
    PE_SECTION_HEADER   sectionTable[MAX_SECTION_COUNT];
    PE_SECTION_DATA     reservedData;
    PE_SECTION_DATA     sections[MAX_SECTION_COUNT];
    PE_IMPORT_DLL       importTable;
    PE_IMPORT_DLL       newImports;

    PEFile();
    PEFile(char* filePath);
    ~PEFile();
    bool                loadFromFile(char* filePath);
    bool                loadFromMemory(char* memoryAddress);
    bool                saveToFile(char* filePath);
    int                 addSection(char* name, DWORD size, bool isExecutable);
    void                addImport(char* dllName, char** functions, int functionCount);
    void                commit();

private:
    char*               peMemory;

    void                init();
    bool                readFileData(char* filePath);
    bool                checkValidity();
    bool                readHeaders();
    bool                readBody();
    bool                readImportTable();
    bool                writePadding(HANDLE fileHandle, long paddingSize);
    void                unloadFile();

    void                buildImportTable();
    char*               buildNewImports(DWORD baseRVA);
    DWORD               calcNewImportsSize(DWORD &sizeDlls, DWORD &sizeFunctions, DWORD &sizeStrings);

    DWORD               alignNumber(DWORD number, DWORD alignment);
    DWORD               rvaToOffset(DWORD rva);
    DWORD               offsetToRVA(DWORD offset);

    void                fixReservedData();
    void                fixHeaders();
    void                fixSectionTable();

};
//==============================================================================
```

Code: `PEFile.cpp`

```
/*******************************************************************************
********************************   Team AT4RE   ********************************
********************************************************************************
*******************  PLEASE DON'T CHANGE/REMOVE THIS HEADER  *******************
********************************************************************************
**                                                                            **
**  Title:      PEFile class.                                                 **
**  Desc:       A handy class to manipulate pe files.                         **
**  Author:     MohammadHi [ in4matics at hotmail dot com ]                   **
**  WwW:        AT4RE      [ http://www.at4re.com ]                           **
**  Date:       2008-01-28                                                    **
**                                                                            **
********************************************************************************
*******************************************************************************/

#include "PEFile.h"
#include <math.h>
//==============================================================================
#define DEBUG_ENABLED true;
#ifdef DEBUG_ENABLED
    #define echo(x)         MessageBox(0, x, "DEBUG", MB_ICONERROR);
    #define echo2(x, y)     { char v[256]; strcpy_s(v, 256, x); strcat_s(v, 256, y); echo(v); }
    #define echo3(x, y, z)  { char w[256]; strcpy_s(w, 256, x); strcat_s(w, 256, y); echo2(w, z); }
#else
    #define echo(x) ;
    #define echo2(x, y) ;
    #define echo3(x, y, z) ;
#endif
//==============================================================================
PEFile::PEFile() {
    init();
}
//==============================================================================
PEFile::PEFile(char* filePath) {
    init();
    loadFromFile(filePath);
}
//==============================================================================
PEFile::~PEFile() {
    unloadFile();
}
//==============================================================================
void PEFile::init() {
    peMemory = NULL;
    ZeroMemory(&newImports, sizeof(PE_IMPORT_DLL));
}
//==============================================================================
bool PEFile::readFileData(char* filePath) {
    // open the file for read
    HANDLE fileHandle = CreateFile(filePath, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (fileHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        echo3("Couldn't open file : [", filePath, "]");
        return false;
    }

    // get the file size
    DWORD fileSize = GetFileSize(fileHandle, 0);
    if (fileSize == 0) {
        CloseHandle(fileHandle);
        echo3("File size is ZeR0! : [", filePath, "]");
        return false;
    }

    // allocate memory to read the pe file (note that we used VirtualAlloc not GlobalAlloc!)
    peMemory = (char*)VirtualAlloc(NULL, fileSize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    if (peMemory == NULL) {
        CloseHandle(fileHandle);
        echo("Couldn't allocate memory!");
        return false;
    }

    DWORD bytesRead;
    // read whole file data
    if (!ReadFile(fileHandle, peMemory, fileSize, &bytesRead, NULL) || bytesRead != fileSize) {
        CloseHandle(fileHandle);
        echo3("Couldn't read file! : [", filePath, "]");
        return false;
    }

    // close the file
    CloseHandle(fileHandle);

    return true;
}
//==============================================================================
bool PEFile::checkValidity() {
    // 'dosHeader.Signature' must be "MZ" && 'peHeaders.Signature' must be "PE\0\0"
    if (dosHeader.Signature != IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE || peHeaders.Signature != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE) {
        unloadFile();
        echo("Invalid PE file!");
        return false;
    }

    if (peHeaders.FileHeader.NumberOfSections > MAX_SECTION_COUNT) {
        unloadFile();
        echo("Number of sections > MAX_SECTION_COUNT !");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
//==============================================================================
bool PEFile::readHeaders() {
    // read dos/pe headers
    CopyMemory(&dosHeader, peMemory, sizeof(PE_DOS_HEADER));
    dosStub.RawData = peMemory + sizeof(PE_DOS_HEADER);
    dosStub.Size = dosHeader.PEHeaderOffset - sizeof(PE_DOS_HEADER);
    CopyMemory(&peHeaders, peMemory + dosHeader.PEHeaderOffset, sizeof(PE_NT_HEADERS));

    // check validity of the file to ensure that we loaded a "PE File" not another thing!
    if (!checkValidity()) {
        return false;
    }

    // read section table
    ZeroMemory(sectionTable, sizeof(sectionTable));
    CopyMemory(sectionTable, peMemory + dosHeader.PEHeaderOffset + sizeof(PE_NT_HEADERS), 
        peHeaders.FileHeader.NumberOfSections * sizeof(PE_SECTION_HEADER));

    return true;
}
//==============================================================================
bool PEFile::readBody() {
    // read reserved data
    DWORD reservedDataOffset = dosHeader.PEHeaderOffset + sizeof(PE_NT_HEADERS) + 
        peHeaders.FileHeader.NumberOfSections * sizeof(PE_SECTION_HEADER);

    reservedData.Offset = reservedDataOffset;
    reservedData.RawData = peMemory + reservedDataOffset;
    /*reservedData.Size = peHeaders.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders - reservedDataOffset;*/
    if (sectionTable[0].PointerToRawData > 0) {
        reservedData.Size = sectionTable[0].PointerToRawData - reservedDataOffset;
    } else {
        reservedData.Size = sectionTable[0].VirtualAddress - reservedDataOffset;
    }

    // read sections
    for (int i = 0; i < peHeaders.FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++) {
        sections[i].Offset = sectionTable[i].PointerToRawData;
        sections[i].RawData = peMemory + sectionTable[i].PointerToRawData;
        sections[i].Size = sectionTable[i].SizeOfRawData;
    }

    return true;
}
//==============================================================================
bool PEFile::readImportTable() {
    DWORD tableRVA = peHeaders.OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress;
    DWORD tableOffset = rvaToOffset(tableRVA);
    if (tableOffset == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&importTable, sizeof(PE_IMPORT_DLL));

    IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR* importDesc = (IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR*)(peMemory + tableOffset);
    IMAGE_THUNK_DATA* importThunk;
    PE_IMPORT_DLL* importDll = &this->importTable;
    PE_IMPORT_FUNCTION* importFunction;

    while (true) {
        importDll->DllName = (char*)(peMemory + rvaToOffset(importDesc->Name));
        if (importDesc->OriginalFirstThunk > 0) {
            importThunk = (IMAGE_THUNK_DATA*)(peMemory + rvaToOffset(importDesc->OriginalFirstThunk));
        } else {
            importThunk = (IMAGE_THUNK_DATA*)(peMemory + rvaToOffset(importDesc->FirstThunk));
        }

        importDll->Functions = new PE_IMPORT_FUNCTION();
        ZeroMemory(importDll->Functions, sizeof(PE_IMPORT_FUNCTION));
        importFunction = importDll->Functions;
        while (true) {
            if ((importThunk->u1.Ordinal & IMAGE_ORDINAL_FLAG32) == IMAGE_ORDINAL_FLAG32) {
                importFunction->FunctionId = IMAGE_ORDINAL32(importThunk->u1.Ordinal);
            } else {
                DWORD nameOffset = rvaToOffset(importThunk->u1.AddressOfData);
                importFunction->FunctionName = (char*)(peMemory + nameOffset + 2);
            }

            importThunk = (IMAGE_THUNK_DATA*)((char*)importThunk + sizeof(IMAGE_THUNK_DATA));
            if (importThunk->u1.AddressOfData == 0) {
                break;
            }
            importFunction->Next = new PE_IMPORT_FUNCTION();
            ZeroMemory(importFunction->Next, sizeof(PE_IMPORT_FUNCTION));
            importFunction = importFunction->Next;
        }

        importDesc = (IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR*)((char*)importDesc + sizeof(IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR));
        if (importDesc->Name == 0) {
            break;
        }
        importDll->Next = new PE_IMPORT_DLL();
        ZeroMemory(importDll->Next, sizeof(PE_IMPORT_DLL));
        importDll = importDll->Next;
    }

    return true;
}
//==============================================================================
bool PEFile::loadFromFile(char* filePath) {
    unloadFile();

    return readFileData(filePath) &&
           readHeaders() &&
           readBody() &&
           readImportTable();
}
//==============================================================================
bool PEFile::loadFromMemory(char* memoryAddress) {
    unloadFile();

    peMemory = memoryAddress;

    return readHeaders()/* &&
           readBody() &&
           readImportTable()*/;
}
//==============================================================================
bool PEFile::saveToFile(char* filePath) {
    commit();
    buildImportTable();

    // create the output file
    HANDLE fileHandle = CreateFile(filePath, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (fileHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        echo("Couldn't create file");
        return false;
    }

    DWORD bytesWritten;

    WriteFile(fileHandle, &dosHeader, sizeof(PE_DOS_HEADER), &bytesWritten, NULL);
    WriteFile(fileHandle, dosStub.RawData, dosStub.Size, &bytesWritten, NULL);
    writePadding(fileHandle, dosHeader.PEHeaderOffset - sizeof(PE_DOS_HEADER) - dosStub.Size);
    WriteFile(fileHandle, &peHeaders, sizeof(PE_NT_HEADERS), &bytesWritten, NULL);
    WriteFile(fileHandle, &sectionTable, peHeaders.FileHeader.NumberOfSections * sizeof(PE_SECTION_HEADER), &bytesWritten, NULL);
    WriteFile(fileHandle, reservedData.RawData, reservedData.Size, &bytesWritten, NULL);

    for (int i = 0; i < peHeaders.FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++) {
        writePadding(fileHandle, sectionTable[i].PointerToRawData - GetFileSize(fileHandle, NULL));
        WriteFile(fileHandle, sections[i].RawData, sections[i].Size, &bytesWritten, NULL);
    }

    CloseHandle(fileHandle);

    return true;
}
//==============================================================================
bool PEFile::writePadding(HANDLE fileHandle, long paddingSize) {
    if (paddingSize <= 0)
        return false;

    DWORD bytesWritten;
    char* padding = new char[paddingSize];
    memset(padding, 0, paddingSize);
    WriteFile(fileHandle, padding, paddingSize, &bytesWritten, NULL);
    delete padding;

    return (bytesWritten == paddingSize);
}
//==============================================================================
void PEFile::unloadFile() {
    if (peMemory != NULL) {
        VirtualFree(peMemory, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        peMemory = NULL;
    }
}
//==============================================================================
void PEFile::buildImportTable() {
    DWORD sizeDlls = 0;
    DWORD sizeFunctions = 0;
    DWORD sizeStrings = 0;
    DWORD newImportsSize = calcNewImportsSize(sizeDlls, sizeFunctions, sizeStrings);

    // we'll move the old dll list to the new import table, so we'll calc its size
    DWORD oldImportDllsSize = 0;
    PE_IMPORT_DLL* importDll = &this->importTable;
    while (importDll != NULL) {
        oldImportDllsSize += sizeof(IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR);
        importDll = importDll->Next;
    }

    // add a new section to handle the new import table
    int index = addSection(SECTION_IMPORT, oldImportDllsSize + newImportsSize, false);

    // copy old import dll list
    DWORD oldImportTableRVA = peHeaders.OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress;
    DWORD oldImportTableOffset = rvaToOffset(oldImportTableRVA);
    CopyMemory(sections[index].RawData, peMemory + oldImportTableOffset, oldImportDllsSize);

    // copy new imports
    char* newImportsData = buildNewImports(sectionTable[index].VirtualAddress + oldImportDllsSize);
    CopyMemory(sections[index].RawData + oldImportDllsSize, newImportsData, newImportsSize);

    peHeaders.OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress = sectionTable[index].VirtualAddress;
    peHeaders.OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].Size = sectionTable[index].SizeOfRawData;
    peHeaders.OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT].VirtualAddress = 0;
    peHeaders.OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT].Size = 0;
}
//==============================================================================
char* PEFile::buildNewImports(DWORD baseRVA) {
    commit();

    IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR importDesc;
    IMAGE_THUNK_DATA importThunk;
    PE_IMPORT_DLL* importDll;
    PE_IMPORT_FUNCTION* importFunction;

    DWORD sizeDlls = 0;
    DWORD sizeFunctions = 0;
    DWORD sizeStrings = 0;
    DWORD newImportsSize = calcNewImportsSize(sizeDlls, sizeFunctions, sizeStrings);
    DWORD offsetDlls = 0;
    DWORD offsetFunctions = sizeDlls;
    DWORD offsetStrings = sizeDlls + 2 * sizeFunctions;

    char* buffer = new char[newImportsSize];
    ZeroMemory(buffer, newImportsSize);

    importDll = &newImports;
    while (importDll != NULL) {
        ZeroMemory(&importDesc, sizeof(IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR));
        importDesc.OriginalFirstThunk = baseRVA + offsetFunctions;
        importDesc.FirstThunk = baseRVA + offsetFunctions + sizeFunctions;
        importDesc.Name = baseRVA + offsetStrings;
        CopyMemory(buffer + offsetStrings, importDll->DllName, strlen(importDll->DllName));     
        offsetStrings += alignNumber((DWORD)strlen(importDll->DllName) + 1, 2);

        CopyMemory(buffer + offsetDlls, &importDesc, sizeof(IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR));
        offsetDlls += sizeof(IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR);

        importFunction = importDll->Functions;
        while (importFunction != NULL) {
            ZeroMemory(&importThunk, sizeof(IMAGE_THUNK_DATA));
            if (importFunction->FunctionId != 0) {
                importThunk.u1.Ordinal = importFunction->FunctionId | IMAGE_ORDINAL_FLAG32;
            } else {
                importThunk.u1.AddressOfData = baseRVA + offsetStrings;
                CopyMemory(buffer + offsetStrings + 2, importFunction->FunctionName, strlen(importFunction->FunctionName));     
                offsetStrings += 2 + alignNumber((DWORD)strlen(importFunction->FunctionName) + 1, 2);
            }

            CopyMemory(buffer + offsetFunctions, &importThunk, sizeof(IMAGE_THUNK_DATA));
            CopyMemory(buffer + offsetFunctions + sizeFunctions, &importThunk, sizeof(IMAGE_THUNK_DATA));
            offsetFunctions += sizeof(IMAGE_THUNK_DATA);

            importFunction = importFunction->Next;
        }
        offsetFunctions += sizeof(IMAGE_THUNK_DATA);

        importDll = importDll->Next;
    }

    return buffer;
}
//==============================================================================
DWORD PEFile::calcNewImportsSize(DWORD &sizeDlls, DWORD &sizeFunctions, DWORD &sizeStrings) {
    PE_IMPORT_DLL* importDll = &this->newImports;
    PE_IMPORT_FUNCTION* importFunction;

    // calc added imports size
    while (importDll != NULL) {
        sizeDlls += sizeof(IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR);
        sizeStrings += alignNumber((DWORD)strlen(importDll->DllName) + 1, 2);
        importFunction = importDll->Functions;
        while (importFunction != NULL) {
            sizeFunctions += sizeof(IMAGE_THUNK_DATA);
            if (importFunction->FunctionId == 0) {
                sizeStrings += 2 + alignNumber((DWORD)strlen(importFunction->FunctionName) + 1, 2);
            }
            importFunction = importFunction->Next;
        }
        sizeFunctions += sizeof(IMAGE_THUNK_DATA); // for the terminator thunk data
        importDll = importDll->Next;
    }
    sizeDlls += sizeof(IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR); // for the terminator import descriptor

    return sizeDlls + 2 * sizeFunctions + sizeStrings;
}
//==============================================================================
int PEFile::addSection(char* name, DWORD size, bool isExecutable) {
    if (peHeaders.FileHeader.NumberOfSections == MAX_SECTION_COUNT) {
        return -1;
    }

    PE_SECTION_DATA &newSection = sections[peHeaders.FileHeader.NumberOfSections];
    PE_SECTION_HEADER &newSectionHeader = sectionTable[peHeaders.FileHeader.NumberOfSections];
    PE_SECTION_HEADER &lastSectionHeader = sectionTable[peHeaders.FileHeader.NumberOfSections - 1];

    DWORD sectionSize = alignNumber(size, peHeaders.OptionalHeader.FileAlignment);
    DWORD virtualSize = alignNumber(sectionSize, peHeaders.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment);

    DWORD sectionOffset = alignNumber(lastSectionHeader.PointerToRawData + lastSectionHeader.SizeOfRawData, peHeaders.OptionalHeader.FileAlignment);
    DWORD virtualOffset = alignNumber(lastSectionHeader.VirtualAddress + lastSectionHeader.Misc.VirtualSize, peHeaders.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment);

    ZeroMemory(&newSectionHeader, sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER));
    CopyMemory(newSectionHeader.Name, name, (strlen(name) > 8 ? 8 : strlen(name)));

    newSectionHeader.PointerToRawData = sectionOffset;
    newSectionHeader.VirtualAddress = virtualOffset;
    newSectionHeader.SizeOfRawData = sectionSize;
    newSectionHeader.Misc.VirtualSize = virtualSize;
    newSectionHeader.Characteristics = //0xC0000040; 
        IMAGE_SCN_MEM_READ | IMAGE_SCN_MEM_WRITE | IMAGE_SCN_CNT_INITIALIZED_DATA;

    if (isExecutable) {
        newSectionHeader.Characteristics |= IMAGE_SCN_CNT_CODE | IMAGE_SCN_MEM_EXECUTE;
    }

    newSection.RawData = (char*)GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED | GMEM_ZEROINIT, sectionSize);
    newSection.Size = sectionSize;

    peHeaders.FileHeader.NumberOfSections++;
    if (reservedData.Size > 0) {
        reservedData.Size -= sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER);
    }

    // return new section index
    return peHeaders.FileHeader.NumberOfSections - 1;
}
//==============================================================================
void PEFile::addImport(char* dllName, char** functions, int functionCount) {
    PE_IMPORT_DLL* importDll = &this->newImports;
    PE_IMPORT_FUNCTION* importFunction;

    if (newImports.DllName != NULL) {
        while (importDll->Next != NULL) {
            importDll = importDll->Next;
        }
        importDll->Next = new PE_IMPORT_DLL();
        importDll = importDll->Next;
    }
    importDll->DllName = dllName;
    importDll->Functions = new PE_IMPORT_FUNCTION();
    importDll->Next = NULL;

    importFunction = importDll->Functions;
    importFunction->FunctionName = functions[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < functionCount; i++) {
        importFunction->Next = new PE_IMPORT_FUNCTION();
        importFunction = importFunction->Next;
        importFunction->FunctionName = functions[i];
    }
    importFunction->Next = NULL;
}
//==============================================================================
DWORD PEFile::alignNumber(DWORD number, DWORD alignment) {
    return (DWORD)(ceil(number / (alignment + 0.0)) * alignment);
}
//==============================================================================
DWORD PEFile::rvaToOffset(DWORD rva) {
    for (int i = 0; i < peHeaders.FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++) {
        if (rva >= sectionTable[i].VirtualAddress &&
            rva < sectionTable[i].VirtualAddress + sectionTable[i].Misc.VirtualSize) {
            return sectionTable[i].PointerToRawData + (rva - sectionTable[i].VirtualAddress);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
//==============================================================================
DWORD PEFile::offsetToRVA(DWORD offset) {
    for (int i = 0; i < peHeaders.FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++) {
        if (offset >= sectionTable[i].PointerToRawData &&
            offset < sectionTable[i].PointerToRawData + sectionTable[i].SizeOfRawData) {
            return sectionTable[i].VirtualAddress + (offset - sectionTable[i].PointerToRawData);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
//==============================================================================
void PEFile::commit() {
    fixReservedData();
    fixHeaders();
    fixSectionTable();
}
//==============================================================================
void PEFile::fixReservedData() {
    DWORD dirIndex = 0;
    for (dirIndex = 0; dirIndex < peHeaders.OptionalHeader.NumberOfRvaAndSizes; dirIndex++) {
        if (peHeaders.OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[dirIndex].VirtualAddress > 0 && 
            peHeaders.OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[dirIndex].VirtualAddress >= reservedData.Offset &&
            peHeaders.OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[dirIndex].VirtualAddress < reservedData.Size) {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (dirIndex == peHeaders.OptionalHeader.NumberOfRvaAndSizes) {
        return;
    }

    int sectionIndex = addSection(SECTION_RESERV, reservedData.Size, false);
    CopyMemory(sections[sectionIndex].RawData, reservedData.RawData, reservedData.Size);

    for (dirIndex = 0; dirIndex < peHeaders.OptionalHeader.NumberOfRvaAndSizes; dirIndex++) {
        if (peHeaders.OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[dirIndex].VirtualAddress > 0 &&
            peHeaders.OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[dirIndex].VirtualAddress >= reservedData.Offset &&
            peHeaders.OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[dirIndex].VirtualAddress < reservedData.Size) {
            peHeaders.OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[dirIndex].VirtualAddress += 
                sectionTable[sectionIndex].VirtualAddress - reservedData.Offset;
        }
    }

    reservedData.Size = 0;
}
//==============================================================================
void PEFile::fixHeaders() {
    peHeaders.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders = alignNumber(dosHeader.PEHeaderOffset + peHeaders.FileHeader.SizeOfOptionalHeader +
        peHeaders.FileHeader.NumberOfSections * sizeof(PE_SECTION_HEADER), peHeaders.OptionalHeader.FileAlignment);

    DWORD imageSize = peHeaders.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders;
    for (int i = 0; i < peHeaders.FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++) {
        imageSize += alignNumber(sectionTable[i].Misc.VirtualSize, peHeaders.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment);
    }
    peHeaders.OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage = alignNumber(imageSize, peHeaders.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment);

    peHeaders.OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BOUND_IMPORT].VirtualAddress = 0;
    peHeaders.OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BOUND_IMPORT].Size = 0;
}
//==============================================================================
void PEFile::fixSectionTable() {
    DWORD offset = peHeaders.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders;
    for (int i = 0; i < peHeaders.FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++) {
        sectionTable[i].Characteristics |= IMAGE_SCN_MEM_WRITE;
        offset = alignNumber(offset, peHeaders.OptionalHeader.FileAlignment);
        sectionTable[i].PointerToRawData = offset;
        //sectionTable[i].SizeOfRawData = alignNumber(offset + sectionTable[i].Misc.VirtualSize, peHeaders.OptionalHeader.FileAlignment);
        offset += sectionTable[i].SizeOfRawData;
    }
}
//==============================================================================
```

```
#include "PEFile.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Open the input file
    PEFile pe("1.exe");

    // Add "MessageBoxA" & "ShowWindow" functions to the import table
    char* functions[] = { "MessageBoxA", "ShowWindow" };
    pe.addImport("user32.dll", functions, 2);

    // Add a new section named ".at4re" with size "0x1000" byte
    pe.addSection(".at4re", 0x1000, false);

    // Save the modified file
    pe.saveToFile("1+.exe");
}
```

Comment: m-PEFile supports only 32 bit PE, Is there a 64 bit PE compatible code?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [PeNet](https://github.com/secana/PeNet) library to add a new import with just one line of code. For an example see here: [Adding Imports](http://secana.github.io/PeNet/articles/imports.html)

```cs
var peFile = new PeFile("myapp.exe");
peFile.AddImport("gdi32.dll", "StartPage");
```

Comment: Thanks! Was this available in 2012?

Comment: No it wasn't. I've added the option for future refence as most links here seem dead. Disclaimer: I'm the author of the library.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for such program myself. I failed too.
But it is very easily done by hand.
If you need to automate it then you can make your own program.
Go to http://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/ or http://www.rohitab.com
People there will be able to help you write your own program.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll ask there.