# Extending the import table of the Windows PE

Tags: windows, portable-executable

I'd like to patch some `Windows` `PE` file. First I have to add to the `PE` in question some import function/s from `user32.dll`. To do that i used the [PE-Add-Imports](https://github.com/fatrolls/PE-Add-Imports/blob/master/README.md) C++ utility like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688471/add-an-entry-to-the-import-table-of-pe) thread. I've compiled and run the patching program on the desired PE file but there have to be sth. wrong with the `addImport` function because after running the patched PE the import table was CLEARED and the modified PE is no longer runnable!

Here is the code (the original example code from the doc):

```
#include "PEFile.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Open the input file
    PEFile pe("MyDll_Test.exe");

    // Add "MessageBoxA" & "ShowWindow" functions to the import table
    char* functions[] = { "MessageBoxA", "ShowWindow" };
    pe.addImport("user32.dll", functions, 2);
    
    // Add a new section named ".at4re" with size "0x1000" byte
    pe.addSection(".at4re", 0x1000, false);
    
    // Save the modified file
    pe.saveToFile("MyDll_Test2.exe");
}
```